# BFS implementation in C doesn't terminate

Tags: c, breadth-first-search

This is my implementation of BFS in C

```
void bfs(int* vertices, Edge* edges, int num_vertices, int num_edges){

    int level = 0;
    int modified;

    //continue looping till all vertices have not been updated
    do{
        modified = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < num_edges; ++i)
        {

            int first = edges[i].first;
            int second = edges[i].second;

            if ((vertices[first] == level) &&(vertices[second] == -1))
            {
                vertices[second] = level + 1;
                modified = 0;

            }else if (vertices[second]== level && (vertices[first] == -1))
            {
                vertices[first] = level + 1;
                modified = 0;

            }

        }//end of for
        level++;
    }while(modified != 0);


}
```

The code is supposed to write the level of each vertex corresponsding to a starting vertex in a vetices array. The array is initialized using this function.

```
void initialize_vertices(int* vertices, int size, int start_vertex){

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        if(i == start_vertex){
            vertices[i] = 0;
        }else{
            vertices[i] = -1;
        }

    }

}
```

An edge is defined as follows

```
    typedef struct Edge{
        int first;
        int second;
    }Edge;
```

This is my calling main function.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    const int NUM_VERTICES = 128;
    const int NUM_EDGES = 128;
    const int START_VERTEX = 25;


    clock_t begin, end;
    double time_spent;

    int vertices[NUM_VERTICES];
    Edge edges[NUM_EDGES];



    //data set
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EDGES; ++i)   
    {
        edges[i].first = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
        edges[i].second = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
    }



    initialize_vertices(vertices, NUM_VERTICES, START_VERTEX);


    begin = clock();
    bfs(vertices, edges, NUM_VERTICES, NUM_EDGES);
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    printf("Time taken: %f\n", time_spent);

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VERTICES; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d : %d", i, vertices[i]);
        printf(((i % 4) != 3) ? "\t":"\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The issue is that the code never terminates. What am I doing wrong, any help appreciated.

Comment: It is an implementation of BFS where the input is an array of edge list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `modified` logic is flawed.

By default, you are setting `modified` to `1`, which I guess means that something has been modified.

Then

```
}while(modified != 0);
```

correctly loops if anything has been modified.

You want to initially set `modified` to `0` and change it to `1` in the inner `if`.

Comment: I'm trying to run the while loop till something has not been modified.

Comment: And you are doing the exact opposite, running the loop until something *has* been modified.

Comment: How do I modify the code such that the for loop is run over and over again till something is modified in the vertices array. Once there is no modification it can the while loop terminates.

Comment: @Su_ Read the last line in my answer.

Comment: I tried doing that and the code modifies nothing at all, as in no element of the vertices array was modified and the program terminates.

Answer (score 1):

Yo reenter the loop if you *don't* modify anything. That seems to be your problem.

You set `modified = 1` at the beginning of your loop and only change that to `0` if something changed. When you ask in the end `modified != 0` it will return `true` if and only if there was no change.